# how to send to special number in the new hangouts

Tags: sms, google-hangouts

before the update I can send messages to number like "2200" no problem but since the update hangouts instantly adds +63 to the numbers and now I can send sms to it and it doesn't even let me compose a new sms for that number.. please help I love using hang outs as my default sms messenger so please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You to access Hangouts from the website version https://hangouts.google.com/ and then input the number that you want to send a text to once the conversation is created you can access the conversation from your phone.